# Saving values comma separated in database but throw mismatch parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I have this hidden field in my form

```
{{ Form::hidden('doc', $ansres)  }}
```

When I `dd($ansres)` I receive following

```
string(3) "2,3"
```

When I try to save this into database I receive the error

> ErrorException: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

What I've tried in my controller before saving is to explode the `Input::get('doc')` like this

```
$product = new Product();
$files = explode(",",Input::get('doc'));
$product->documents = $files;
$product->save();
```

Why I still get this error since `dd()` show that it is string?

Update: $ansres

```
foreach($cart as $doc)
{
    $documents[] = $doc['doc'];
}
$ansres = implode(",",$documents);
```

Comment: before `$files` try to `dd(Input::get('doc'))` first

Comment: Again this one `string(3) "2,3"`

Comment: And on the view source of the page I see this `<input name="doc" type="hidden" value="2,3">`

Comment: `dd($files);` return this `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" }`

Comment: From where the value of `$ansres` is coming from ?

Comment: you have to json_encode the value before saving it to the DB

Comment: @JenisPatel I've updated the question with from where $ansres come. Rohit, I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: I'm not sure that json_encode will do this. Also I don't want to store encoded json in database. I want to simply save 2,3,4,5.. etc

Comment: What is the output of `$cart` ?

Comment: @JenisPatel it is array: `array(2) { [1]=> array(1) { ["doc"]=> int(2) } [2]=> array(1) { ["doc"]=> int(3) } }`

Comment: Why you are exploding this `Input::get('doc')` and converting it again to an array ? you want to save it as a string right ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how exactly to do this and checked some other threads here and trying different ways. That's why. Can you show me how?

Comment: If I do just `$product->documents = Input::get('doc');` it saves `0`

Comment: what is the data type of `documents` column in database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already getting string value so there is no point of converting it again in `array` using `explode`. So just try to save the comma separated values as it is:

```
$product = new Product();
// $files = explode(",",Input::get('doc')); removing explode function
$product->documents = Input::get('doc'); 
$product->save();
```

**Edit:** I am assuming, the `documents` column is of `varchar` data type in the database.

Comment: Oh, god. I've spend so much time on this that I completely forget about the database column.

Comment: Glad, it works for you. Kindly accept the answer if it helps you :)